# facing issue in calling graph api online meeting api getting response code 400

Tags: microsoft-teams

[sending requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skYkF.png)

getting this response

```json
{
  "error":{
    "code":"AuthenticationError",
    "message":"Error authenticating with resource",
    "innerError":{
      "date":"2020-10-14T19:25:56",
      "request-id":"2b4a3ec1-7923-4940-8827-03b8161eada2",
      "client-request-id":"2b4a3ec1-7923-4940-8827-03b8161eada2"
    }
  }
}
```

`<Response [400]>`

Comment: Please edit your question and replace the screenshot of your request with properly formatted text.

Comment: i uploaded but it is showing as a link "sending request"

Comment: Could you please check permission required for online meeting api as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: Please check if your app have [OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) permission?